# The meaning of "instrumental" here

Tags: meaning

> It's a very instrumental view of education and how it relates to their needs.

According to the dictionary it's "relating to something's function as a means to an end." But I don't get what this word implies in the sentence above.

Comment: Please link and attribute your quoted definition. 'The dictionary' is extremely unhelpful. OED? Boy's Big?

Comment: How about another dictionary? [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/instrumental) gives 1. "Serving as a means of pursuing an aim or policy" in addition to your definition. Essentially, *instrumental* here means looking at education as a method (i.e. instrument) of accomplishing some goal (i.e., end).

Comment: I assume there is the 'person-orientated v result-orientated' tension/conflict in the writer's mind here. Turning out high-functioning sociopaths, perhaps.

Comment: There are 3 pronouns with unspecified referents (_it, it_, and _their_) in the sentence, plus one lexical noun (_education_) which is used very generally without context. When we have some idea what **they** mean, we'll be in a better position to deal with _instrumental_ here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Instrumental* is a transferred epithet here: strictly speaking the view is not itself instrumental, but it treats education as something instrumental. Once that is realised, a dictionary definition can be plugged in without any difficulty: the view treats education as a means to some end. The implied contrast is with treating education as something that is valuable in itself, regardless of its consequences.